# Hovering an image in front of an image

Tags: css, image, hover, html

I am a new user to html and css and am making my first website.  I am trying to take an image and have an image hover over it, except appear as a different color.  I read other posts similar to this, but am still having difficulties.

This is the portion of my html:

```
<div id= "silhouette_3">
    <img src= "images/silhouette_kickboxing.gif" />
</div>
```

and this is the css:

```
#silhouette_3 img
{
  float: right;
  margin: 8px 20px 0px 0px;
  padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
}

#silhouette_3 img:hover 
{
  background-image: url('images/silhouette_kickboxing_color.gif');
  z-index: 100;
}
```

I believe one of my issues is that one image is a background image and the other is not, but I am unsure of what else I could try.  Any help out there would be much appreciated.  Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

You're right, the `images/silhouette_kickboxing_color.gif` is a background but `<img src=".."/>` is not.

Here is a solution:

```
<div id= "silhouette_3">
    <img />
</div>

#silhouette_3 img
{
  float: right;
  margin: 8px 20px 0px 0px;
  padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
  background-image: url('images/silhouette_kickboxing.gif');
}

#silhouette_3 img:hover 
{
  background-image: url('images/silhouette_kickboxing_color.gif');
  z-index: 100;
}
```

When the `img` is not actually a image anymore, I prefer you should relace it with a `div`.

Answer (score 1):

**First Image:**

[image]

**Second Image:**

[image]

**CSS**

```
#hovereffects:hover {
    content: url('http://dummyimage.com/100x100/eb00eb/fff');
}
```

## [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ec9gn/126/)

You can also check this **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ec9gn/78/)**

Answer (score 0):

You are right that the problem is one of the image is a `background-image` and the other is not, you can fix it by placing the colored image on top and the default image as the `background-image` then use `opacity` to hide the top layer (colored image) and finally show it on mouseover:

HTML:

```
<div id= "silhouette_3">
    <img src= "images/silhouette_kickboxing_color.gif" />
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#silhouette_3{
  background-image: url('images/silhouette_kickboxing.gif');
}
#silhouette_3 img
{
  float: right;
  margin: 8px 20px 0px 0px;
  padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
  opacity: 0;
}

#silhouette_3:hover img
{
  opacity: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Technically speaking, your code probably works, but the background-image won't show even though it's there when you hover your mouse over it because a background can't show above its foreground.  You can't set the z-index just on the background-image because it's not a separate element.

There are many ways to accomplish this.  You could set a background image on the div, then set your other image only to show when you hover over it.

For example:

HTML:

```
<div id= "silhouette_3">
    <img src= "http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports" />
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#silhouette_3
{
  float: right;
  margin: 8px 20px 0px 0px;
  padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
  background-image: url("http://lorempixel.com/400/200/abstract");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

#silhouette_3 img {
  visibility: hidden;
}

#silhouette_3:hover img {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

This way, the background-image in the CSS is the one that shows initially and the one in the img tag is the one that shows when you hover over it.

I created a demo at CodePen: http://codepen.io/Ghodmode/pen/foIhJ

**Update**: The images seem to me more like content than presentation, so I'd rather have them in the HTML than the CSS.  I updated my CodePen demo to do it a little differently.  I like this way better ...

HTML:

```
<div id="silhouette_4">
  <img class="img1" src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/city">
  <img class="img2" src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/people">
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#silhouette_4 img {
  float: right;
  margin: 8px 20px 0px 0px;
  padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
}

#silhouette_4 .img2 {
  display: none;
}

#silhouette_4:hover .img1 {
  display: none;
}

#silhouette_4:hover .img2 {
  display: inline-block;
}
```